# Class css added with jquery not appliyed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a simple twitter-bootstrap 3 input text :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
```

with jquery i add a (`hasError`) class to put border color with red , this is `hasError` Class :

```
.hasError{
    border-color: #a94442;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
```

the class is added but its not appliyed , i think that class (`form-control`) has more priority .. how can i resolve this please ?

Comment: Can you give us the jQuery?

Comment: You can try adding it here, this JSFiddle has bootstrap in it: https://jsfiddle.net/z824m656/3/ Also I added the class and it works there.

Comment: $('#idInput').addClass("hasError"); be sure that the class hasError is added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it may be a [CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) problem. If this is your own style rule, try changing it to the following:

```css
input.form-control.hasError {
    border-color: #a94442;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
```

If you are using the built-in styling from bootstrap, you need to apply the has-error class to the parent element for the error styling to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z824m656/4/

I changed your jQuery to:

```
$('#yourInput').addClass('hasError');
```

And added the `id` `yourInput` to, well, your input. Now it works.